# redhat sso version upgrade to 7.6-24

Tags: redhat-sso

I have upgraded redhatsso from 7.6-23 to 7.6.24 successfully. Everything works fine and looks good but login page UI not looking good, Looks like old, Want to how to fix it or any UI related changes in this redhat sso version. [image: Attached image of login page UI]